# How to open a wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress

I was asked to correct styles in CSS on the Wordpress site. I do not have access to their server, so I need to edit on my local server.

There are files in the wp-content folder.

I installed Wordpress on a local server (I did not work in Wordpress Before), threw this wp-content file there. And here's what happened:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbNXo.png)

Code (197 line):

```
<div class="bt bt-language d-none d-md-block">
  <?php
  $languages = icl_get_languages('skip_missing=0');
  foreach ($languages as $key =>
  $value) { if ($value['active'] == 0) { $lg = $value['language_code']; $href =
  $value['url']; break; } } ?>
  <a class="" href="<?php echo $href; ?>">
    <span><?php echo $lg; ?></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: "icl_get_languages" is not a wordpress function. what do you want to customise ?

Comment: Do you have wpml installed?

Comment: @Kaperto the **wp-content file** was sent to me by the client. I do not have access to **Wp-admin**. Want open have themselves on wordpress this site to see that there at all is

Comment: @miguelcalderons Yes, WPML installed

Answer (score 0):

Access wordpress backend and go to Appearance and then choose Editor .. You should be able to add CSS or modify existing from here. Just make sure a backup of the entire file text before modification... Just in case. Use the same technique on the live site.. You do not need to setup local environment.

Comment: The client sent me a wp-content file without access to the server and Wordpress Admin.
So I need to open the site on my local hosting to see the changes I make in the code.
And as a result the client wants to get a **patch** file that he will add to his server and this file should fix all the errors